# area common to two intersecting circles is not filled with desired colour while using floodfill algorithm

Tags: c, opengl

I have made some changes in code.  Code and output I am getting is shown below. I am tying to fill the common area of two intersecting circle with colour other than boundary colour. Two circles are drawn but the common area remains as it is I am using flood fill to fill the common area.

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>

struct Color{
  GLfloat red, green, blue;
};

struct Color getPixel(GLint x, GLint y){        // gets the color of the pixel at (x,y) 
    struct Color c;
    GLfloat color[4];
    glReadPixels(x,y,1,1,GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, color);
    c.red = color[0]; 
    c.green = color[1];     
    c.blue = color[2];  
    return c;
}

void setPixel(GLint x, GLint y,struct Color c){
     printf("\n i am at the cordinate %d and %d",x,y);
    glColor3f(c.red, c.green, c.blue);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(x,y);
    glEnd();
}

void init()
     {
        glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
        gluOrtho2D(0.0,300.0,0.0,300.0);
     }

void drawPixel(int x,int y)
{
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(x,y);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void Boundary_fill(GLint x,GLint y,struct Color thisColor) {       
    struct Color boundary_color;
    boundary_color.red=0.0;
    boundary_color.green=0.0;
    boundary_color.blue=1.0;
    struct Color nextpixel=getPixel(x,y);
    printf("\n colour of pixel pixel to be filled=%f,%f,%f",nextpixel.red,nextpixel.green,nextpixel.blue);
    if((nextpixel.red!=boundary_color.red)&&(nextpixel.blue!=boundary_color.blue)&&(nextpixel.green!=boundary_color.green) || (nextpixel.red!=thisColor.red) && (nextpixel.blue!=thisColor.blue)&&(nextpixel.green!=thisColor.green)){

     setPixel(x,y,thisColor);
     Boundary_fill((x+1),y,thisColor);  
     Boundary_fill((x-1),y,thisColor);
     Boundary_fill(x,(y+1),thisColor);
     Boundary_fill(x,(y-1),thisColor);
    }

}

void draw(int x1,int y1, int x, int y){
    drawPixel(x1+x,y1+y);//quadrant1
    drawPixel(x1+x,y1-y);//quadrant2
    drawPixel(x1-x,y1+y);//quadrant3
    drawPixel(x1-x,y1-y);//quadrant4
    drawPixel(x1+y,y1+x);//quadrant5
    drawPixel(x1+y,y1-x);//quadrant6
    drawPixel(x1-y,y1+x);//quadrant7
    drawPixel(x1-y,y1-x);//quadrant8
}

void circle(int px,int py,int r){
printf("\n xcenter=%d,ycenter=%d,radius=%d",px,py,r);
    int a,b;
    float p;
    a=0;
    b=r;
    p=(5/4)-r;

    while(a<=b){
        draw(px,py,a,b);
        if(p<0){
            p=p+(2*a)+1;
        }
        else{
            b=b-1;
            p=p+(2*a)+1-(2*b);
        }
        a=a+1;
    }
}


void Circle(void)
{
    struct Color thisColor;
    thisColor.red=0.0;
    thisColor.blue=0.0;
    thisColor.green=0.0;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0); //blue colour
    glPointSize(2.0);
    GLint x0 = 100;
    GLint y0 = 150;
    circle(x0,y0,50);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    circle(x0+50,y0,25);
     Boundary_fill(x0+25,y0,thisColor);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow("Boundary fill in a circle");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(Circle);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Your color comparison in `Boundary_fill` seems odd.  Are you attempting to say `if (nextpixel!=boundary_color && nextpixel!=thisColor)`?

Comment: yes. you got it right .i am comparing present pixel's color with boundary color and with the color with which i would like to fill the common area of these two circles.

Comment: Checking to see if two colors are not equal would be `(c1.red!=c2.red || c1.green!=c2.green || c1.blue!=c2.blue)` -- use `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: i am trying the code below now i am getting a single horizontal line of black colour (colour with which common area is to be filled) which starts at the boundary of smaller circle and ends at bigger circle. you can see output i am getting at [http://i.imgur.com/PaSS9EY.png?1]    `if((nextpixel.red!=boundary_color.red)&&(nextpixel.blue!=boundary_color.blue)&&(nextpixel.green!=boundary_color.green) || (nextpixel.red!=thisColor.red) && (nextpixel.blue!=thisColor.blue)&&(nextpixel.green!=thisColor.green))`
    `